# Which types of steel would be most appropriate for blunt cutting weaponry on a combat robot?

Tags: materials, steel, robotics

I'm getting more serious about a combat robot design I've been contemplating for several years now (BattleBots, Robot Wars, etc) and find myself overwhelmed by the sheer variegation of ASTM and AISI grades and alloys.  I hope that by detailing the application, those familiar with the nomenclature can steer me in the right direction.

The overall design is a full-body spinner - somewhere around 0.75m in diameter, at least 2500 RPM.  (Approximately 205 MPH weapon speed, though this is a minimum target.)  The circumference is lined with five or six solid-mount blades approximating the size and shape of forestry mauls, though slightly thinner - while primarily relying upon inertia and brute force, I would like to retain some degree of sharpness/cutting.

---

Structural integrity is the key attribute, remaining intact (if deformed to some degree) in spite of high-speed impacts with fixed hazards, opponents, and/or similar spinning weaponry.  Any significant separation would be of serious concern owing to the high-speed rotation.

The blades will be mounted to the outside of the body with high-strength bolts, anchoring roughly half the length and 60% the mass of each individual blade.  (I have no intention of ever welding these pieces as even a fractured blade would be swiftly replaced.)

Withstanding impacts and remaining affixed with minimal distortion is highly desirable.  Retaining a sharp edge would be nice, but this is mostly wishful thinking - for the sake of other traits, some sacrifice must be made.

---

What little I understand of this sort of metallurgy has me looking at ASTM-S1, which seems to be recommended for high-speed impacts and sudden shock-loading.  (Also assuming those terms mean what I think they do.)

Any guidance/recommendations in this department would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "What the other guys use" tend to be 'trade secrets' - understandable, as even a slight advantage can be crucial.  Around $2500 anticipated total budget, though I'm sure it'll be more.  (Though, as these are 'disposable' and replaceable, I'd definitely prefer a cost-effective approach.)

Comment: "Blunt"  and "cutting" are diametrically opposing concepts.   But if you want to learn how to make a strong and sharp blade,  join some of the knife- and sword-maker clubs.  Those guys create frighteningly powerful cutters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer 2: Because you are not building thousands of the Bots, You need to look at materials that are already heat-treated for strength and toughness. Just thinking of the material and not the form : rear axel( of rear wheel drive ), Torsion bars , leaf and coil springs. Construction equipment ; bulldozer blade ( edge if it is  separate material from the bulk, bucket teeth ( if replaceable ), bulldozer treads, blades/arms of big chipper shredder ( hammer mill ) used to chop tree trunks ( Asplendunk is one name). The chipper is almost what you are making. These are educated guess ; all likely have more carbon than optimum for toughness. But it gives some ideas where to look.

Comment: Ooooh!  Right!  Part of what inspired this design was an odd axe/maul-hybrid kind of tool my great-grandfather had - he used it for firewood but I used it to hack apart a 1964 Ford Falcon lickety-split!  But that tool is long gone; don't even recall if there was a brand ID on it.

Answer (score 0):

S-1 is not an ASTM designation , likely AISI tool steel designation  ( likely it is included in some ASTM spec for bar, ). First , what do the other guys use, no use re-inventing the wheel ? Second , is cost a concern? Third, is heat-treating a concern? I would stay away from tool steels ; "all " tool steels primarily hold an edge. So grades like S-1, S-2, H-11, H-12 etc, are the toughest among steels that are intended to hold an edge. And you will pay a premium for "tool steel".  Most of these have about 0.5 % C; C generally lowers toughness. I don't think any contain nickel ; the first alloy you add for toughness. So, I think low alloy steels with medium carbon would give maximum toughness with some hardness. ( AISI/ SAE) 4330 > 8630 > 4130 ; These have 0.3% carbon and are listed in descending Ni content. When quenched and tempered a good one may stop a Charpy hammer ( 240 ft.lb) ( standard toughness test). Also things like 4320 with a carburized case could be used.

Comment: Second case hardening. Pick a ductile steel with high toughness and case harden it. Outer case is hard and wont get easily damaged, interior is ductile to prevent shattering etc.

Comment: Make one - follow the procedure for the samurai swords - soft inner and hard outer...